# Select count of similar values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for user input to questions. They were given the option to give up to five answers to the same question so you have 5 fields with up to five different answers for the same question.

So field1,filed2,field3,field4,field5 could all have the answer "foo"

I want create a query that will return a number count of the total answers in any of the five columns for all users for each possible answer.

So the output would be:

> 'foo' 22 'I like cake' 32 'who cares' 2

I am on the right track with the following but I suspect there is a more elegant solution. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT field1,filed2,field3,field4,field5,
         (sum(CASE WHEN field1='foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
         sum(CASE WHEN field2='foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) +
         sum(CASE WHEN field3='foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) +
         sum(CASE WHEN field4='foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) +
         sum(CASE WHEN field5='foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS count

   FROM items
   GROUP BY field1,filed2,field3,field4,field5
  ;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you get the desired result this query is just fine!

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you need. Have a derived table that returns all columns `UNION ALL`-ed into one. Then do the `GROUP BY`:

```
select field, count(*)
from
(
    select field1 as field from items
    union all
    select field2 from items
    union all
    ...
    select fieldn from items
) dt
group by field
```

Comment: Need to add where condition as well for each selection of 'foo'.

Comment: Interesting. I will incorporate this and see what I get. Looks close.

Comment: @Suraz, wasn't that just an example? If needed, add a WHERE clause just before the GROUP BY.